# Python httplib2 Handling Exceptions

Tags: python, httplib2

I have this very simple code to check if a site is up or down.

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http()
response, content = h.request("http://www.folksdhhkjd.com")
if response.status == 200:
    print "Site is Up"
else:
    print "Site is down"
```

When I enter a valid URL then it properly prints Site is Up because the status is 200 as expected. But, when I enter an invalid URL, should it not print Site is down? Instead it prints an exception something like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\kripya\Desktop\1.py", line 3, in <module>
    response, content = h.request("http://www.folksdhhkjd.com")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1436, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1188, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1129, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.folksdhhkjd.com
```

How can I override this exception and print my custom defined "Site is down" message? Any guidance, please?

**EDIT**

Also one more question... what is the difference between using

```
h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
```

and

```
h = httplib2.Http()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
try:
    response, content = h.request("http://www.folksdhhkjd.com")
    if response.status==200:
        print "Site is Up"
except httplib2.ServerNotFoundError:
    print "Site is Down"
```

The issue with your code is that if the host doesn't respond, the request doesn't return ANY status code, and so the library throws an error (I think it's a peculiarity of the library itself, doing some sort of DNS resolution before trying to make the request).

Comment: wow the basic exception handling is what I should learn now then... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

```
h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
```

Caches the stuff it retrieves in a directory called `.cache` so if you do the same request twice it might not have to actually get everything twice; a file starting with a dot is hidden in POSIX filesystems (like on Linux).

```
h = httplib2.Http()
```

Doesn't cache it's results, so you have to get everything requested every time.

Comment: Oh, so... sounds like best practice is to use `h = httplib2.Http('.cache') ` then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I Voted up both the answers anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to loop through the URLS using a file like this

`sf = open('C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/1.txt', 'r')

for line in sf:
        
        active = 0
        print "Current URL is: \t" + line
        
        try:
                response, content = h.request(line)
                if response.status==200:
                        active=1
        except httplib2.ServerNotFoundError:
                print "Site is Down"
sf.close()`

One of the URLs in the file is http://www.fastbookmarking.info. The site is up. I checked the Status code and its 200

Comment: but for some reason.. it shows me "Site is down" Can anybody explain why?

Comment: It's a problem with the line in the file you're reading. Try `h.request(line.strip())`, and generally make sure the URL is EXACTLY right.

Comment: hey, line.strip() did work! But can you please tell what is wrong with the URL when I use simply line? Because I printed both line and line.strip() both looks the same to me. Sorry!

Comment: One of them has whitespace at the end, most likely a line break in the form of a newline '\n', carriage return, '\r', or both.

Comment: Oh, yes when I say print line it does print the content of the line with a new line character in between! I understand now. Thanks!